# Bcrypt reset password not saving the updated password

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

I'm working on my password reset flow and everything works except the actual bcrypt password reset. Following the "Technique 2 (auto-gen a salt and hash)" from about halfway down in the [bcrypt docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) suggests following below syntax:

**Bcrypt docs syntax**

```
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds);
// Store hash in your password DB.
```

**My function**

```
module.exports.submitNewPassword = async (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body.password, req.params, req.headers.referer );
    const slidedHeaderToken = req.headers.referer.slice(-40);
    const user = await User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: slidedHeaderToken, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } });
    console.log("submitNewPassword user ", user);
    if (!user) {
        console.log("user not found");
        req.flash('error', "Password reset token is invalid or has expired");
        res.render('users/reset')
    } else {
    // hash the new password
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 12);
    // update the user's password
    user.password = hashedPassword;
    user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
    await user.save();
    res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
}
```

The `resetPasswordToken` and `resetPasswordExpires` are set properly in my previous function which emails out the password reset link and saves the two variables to the database.

The if statement logic and `user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;` and `user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;` are executed properly but I can't get `user.password = hashedPassword;` to work.

How do I reset the user's password?

Comment: What happens if you use console log to output `hashedPassword`?

Comment: Hi @node_modules - `console.log(hashedPassword)` gives me `$2b$12$3TheplVYfsDelBhPeEs0kuOXu96ZDjPDR.JZul6ItPUi2mnA0v4R6`

Comment: .. And after `user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;` if you do `console.log(user)`?

Comment: The user object logs with all document fields except `resetPasswordExpires` and `resetPasswordToken`